Does S3 ListBuckets operation return buckets in order?
Does S3's ListBuckets API always return the list of buckets in order? From the AWS CLI, I always get the buckets in order, but I could not find any such guarantee in the S3 documentation. If they do not return the list of buckets in any alphabetical order necessarily, do they always return the buckets in the same order?

The ListBuckets API documentation says nothing about sort order or consistent ordering so you should not make any assumptions about the order they are returned.

No there is no guranteed order or at least not documented, you can simulate order on which attribte you want by using other tools liks jq :
aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name" | jq -r 'sort[]'

Editor: This forum post is the closest I could find, the lack of built-in sorting in the API is derived from the distributed nature of managed services and the architectural decisions made to ensure scalability and performance. https://repost.aws/questions/QUD4vDlkcRTBWVEg2gyC5_7w/sort-results-from-ec2-api
Update:
The question of order can be handled in client side (AWS CLI in this case) or in server side (list-buckets) so by searching in th documentation :
For s3 ls and s3api list-buckets there is no mention of order, in contrary of list-bojects and list-objects-v2 where it's mentioned the order is lexicographical order based on their key names. From here so the reason behind the lack of this sorting in list-buckets can be

'distributed nature of managed services and the architectural
decisions made to ensure scalability and performance'

as @Jeremy Thompson
This is for the server side, in the client side the v2 branch of aws cli in formatter.py which contains the output formatters responsible for printing the response we didn't see any order processing.
So as @John Rotenstein

'Creating buckets named in order and then sorting by name is the
common practice.'

you can also add a logic of folder names for order to you buckets if their is so many

Even if the ordering does not adhere to a specific ordering scheme, are the buckets always returned in the same order if there are no bucket additions/deletions?

Humm, an interesting think is if I list buckets in console or using aws s3 ls or aws s3api list-buckets the order is the same and it's alaphbetical order based on names.  But as I didn't find any documentation about this I'm unable to say this is the order you are guarateed to get or if it's always based on names or not.

@DeskReference the way AWS manages the metadata associated with the S3 object stores is obviously using a No-SQL database. So a safe assumption is the order of buckets returned is never guaranteed. Creating buckets named in order and then sorting by name is the common practice.
